# error is caused by seaborn's pairplot while trying to use it on a subset of a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn

I am trying to use **seaborn's pairplot** on a subset of a dataframe:

```
cat_cols = [i for i in x.columns if x[i].dtype == 'object']
print(cat_cols)
cat_cols.append('target')
print(cat_cols)
dataset  = pd.DataFrame(train, columns = cat_cols) 
print(dataset)

sns.pairplot(dataset, hue = 'target')
plt.show()
```

it is throwing the following error:

```
 No variables found for grid columns.
```

this is how the dataframe looks after subsetting:

```
       cat0 cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4 cat5 cat6 cat7 cat8 cat9    target
0         B    B    B    C    B    B    A    E    C    N  8.113634
1         B    B    A    A    B    D    A    F    A    O  8.481233
2         A    A    A    C    B    D    A    D    A    F  8.364351
3         B    B    A    C    B    D    A    E    C    K  8.049253
4         A    A    A    C    B    D    A    E    A    N  7.972260
...     ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...       ...
299995    B    B    A    A    B    D    A    E    A    I  7.945605
299996    A    B    A    C    B    B    A    E    E    F  7.326118
299997    B    B    A    C    B    C    A    E    G    F  8.706755
299998    A    B    A    C    B    B    A    E    E    I  7.229569
299999    A    A    A    C    A    D    A    E    A    O  8.631146
```

I cant seem to find out why it is not working on '**dataset**'. Does pairplot only works on classified outputs ?

Comment: [seaborn.pairplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) needs at leats two coninuous column to work. This means you need at least two columns with _numeric_ values. On the contrary, in your `dataset`, only `target` is a continuous column, the other are categorical

Comment: Not quite true, @Zephyr — `pairplot` *can* handle categorical variables, but it ignores them by default, so you need to be explicit that you want them (e.g. `vars=df.columns`).

Comment: (That said, scatterplots between two categorical variables won't be especially informative; you may want to try e.g. `kind="hist"`).